# Cannot set start/end manually in MariaDB 10.3 System Versioned Tables

Tags: mariadb

From MariaDB KB:

> mysqldump does not read historical rows from versioned tables, and so
>   historical data will not be backed up. Also, a restore of the
>   timestamps would not be possible as they cannot be defined by an
>   insert/a user.

Not being able to set the system start/end timestamps, I can see no way to migrate existing tables which now track start/end manually.

Doesn't this mean that the AS OF feature is really only useful for new databases or am I missing some way around the limitation?

Comment: Please provide the URL of that quote.  And an example of a table that you fear cannot be reloaded (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`).

Comment: Url is https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/system-versioned-tables/#limitations  As it states, create any system versioned table (the example on their KB page will do), manipulate rows, export it and all version info is lost. There is no way to import system start/end timestamps.

Comment: Use physical backups